# how to loop through this in blog single?

Tags: single

here is the code in single.php
and I want to add the loop.
anywhere I put endif, I am getting error
where can I add it, please?

updated code:

and many thanks in advance.

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="blog-post">
                                <div class="single-post">
                                    <div class="post-thumb">"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="blog thumb" /></div>
                                    <div class="blog-single-content">
                                        <div class="blog-list-content">
                                            <p class="post-meta">Posted By <a href="#"> <?php the_author(); ?> </a></p>
                                            <h3 class="blog-title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                                                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                        </div> <!-- class="blog-list-content" -->                            
                                    </div> <!-- class="blog-single-content" -->
                                </div> <!-- class="single-post" -->
                            </div> <!-- class="blog-post" -->
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Comment: From the looks of it, you're already in The Loop. Functions like `the_*()` are a good indication of this. Some themes skip The Loop on single posts since there's one post to display and it's already loaded.

Comment: thanks for your comment. but in every theme I do not know where to put endif and endwhile. it always gets error. so I want to understand how to add it without getting error

Comment: Maybe [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/374195/edit) with an attempt and users can point out your error. Some good examples are the early Twenty X themes. For example, [Twenty Seventeen single.php](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyseventeen/2.4/single.php). In the above example you wouldn't need to put a loop if you're already in the loop. Also some helpful resources with lots of examples: [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) & [The Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)

Comment: @ Howdy_McGee thanks for your comment. what do you mean by I am already in the loop, please? and I updated the code with the loop

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a syntax error with this line:

```
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

You are missing a colon after `( have_posts() )`.

If it's not a theme related issue as mentioned in the comments if you change it to:
"`if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`"

Also, the `endwhile` should come BEFORE the `endif`.

After making these changes it should work.

See Example Here:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
<?php  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="blog-post">
                                <div class="single-post">
                                    <div class="post-thumb">"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="blog thumb" /></div>
                                    <div class="blog-single-content">
                                        <div class="blog-list-content">
                                            <p class="post-meta">Posted By <a href="#"> <?php the_author(); ?> </a></p>
                                            <h3 class="blog-title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                                                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                        </div> <!-- class="blog-list-content" -->                            
                                    </div> <!-- class="blog-single-content" -->
                                </div> <!-- class="single-post" -->
                            </div> <!-- class="blog-post" -->
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                          
                            <?php comments_template(); ?>
```

I always check my PHP with a code checker here: https://phpcodechecker.com/. I have found it helps a lot when debugging my code.
Hopefully, this works for you!

Comment: thanks for your reply, I put the collon , but unfortunately, still not working and get the error

Comment: Did you move the endwhile to before the endif?

Comment: thanks for your comment. it is still not working. and by the way, it is on the local host xampp